SwiftUI - Adding Button inside of AutoCorrect Suggestion Bar
Anyone know if its possible to add a button to Auto Suggestion Bar? Ended up trying the code below and I was able to add a button on top of the keyboard. But confused if there's an api that allows us to modify autocorrect status bar.
CustomTextField
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct CustomTextfield: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var keyType: UIKeyboardType
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.keyboardType = keyType
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textfield.frame.size.width, height: 44))
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(textfield.doneButtonTapped(button:)))
        toolBar.items = [doneButton]
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
        textfield.leftView = toolBar
        return textfield
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        
    }
}

extension  UITextField{
    @objc func doneButtonTapped(button:UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
}

TestView
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TestView : View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomTextfield(text: $text, keyType: UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 50)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
        )
    }
}


